# RemoteView ADT21 layout parameter

Tags: android, service, widget

I am trying to set the text of a TextView on an AppWidgetProvider class from a Service.
On the service's OnStart() method, I gave this

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
```

But it is showing that 'main' cannot be resolved in "R.layout.main". I am able to assign only integer values as the second parameter. I heard there are issues with ADT21, is this one among them?

And none of the Log.d() statements inside the AppWidgetProvider as well as the service are printing messages on the LogCat.

Please help.

Comment: Just to make sure, check that you're importing correct R class into your Service.

Comment: I did and only the 'main' part is unable to resolve. I am getting a warning that it is unable to instantiate receiver APPWIDGET_UPDATE and APPWIDGET_ENABLED because the process is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. You need to use the `import.android.R` to resolve the R and then delete the import. As simple as that.